# Generic way to access Android protected filesystem (Not to be confused with rooting)

Tags: adb, root-access

I'm trying to get full access to the Android file system on a device without actually rooting the device. Something that could get me into the file system at boot time for example. Looking for a generic way, not just working on single device.

The goal is to remove some protected apps. And because I don't trust KingoRoot.

Phones have a way of updating themselves and this means that the update package should have rights to do anything.

Half-answers are also welcome, as in pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: "Phones have a way of updating themselves" – yes, e.g. by means of flashing a signed "package". But as you don't have the "trusted key" (only the manufacturer/ROM "baker" have it, for security reasons), that way is not available to you: your "packages" would be rejected by the system ("invalid/unknown/untrusted signature").

Comment: In general, this isn't possible... Android is designed NOT to let you access this stuff without root. That said, there maybe some device specific methods if you updated your question with your device you might get an answer. There is also the issue of SELinux and DMverity which will just restore everything on the next boot anyway. And you are right not to trust King(o)root and other similar solutions. But to answer your question there is no "generic" way, if there was rooting wouldn't be an issue at all.

Comment: So that trusted key is probably not just sitting there in plain format for one to retrieve it either right? Well, true that would simplify things a lot for rooting. That's why I'd settle something more intermediate rather than a direct solution. Something that would drop me half way. Just want to be able to tinker with any device to gain root on my own, and (if successful) provide solution to others but in a transparent way rather than some magic.exe that you just have to trust to do it all without messing you up. @i

Comment: You and most if the Android enthusiast community... The proper way to root a device is to unlock the bootloader, use a custom recovery, and flash SuperSU or Magisk, any other method is pretty much a kludge that is device specific. Accessing system files is "privileged" and reserved for digitally signed packages, really if it worked any other way the security of Android would be compromised to a point the device would be unsafe to use in todays world. If you can't unlock the bootloader and perform these steps and want to, then you likely don't have the right device for your needs.

Comment: Well this particular device (LYF phone) actually has "OEM Unlocking - allow the bootloader to be unlocked" option under Dev options. If that's relevant/useful? @acejavelin

Comment: @Emil I am not familiar with this specific device, but this option doesn't unlock the bootloader but just allows that to occur if your manufacturer supports it (which Lyf seems to, at least on some devices). At this point you can load or boot a custom recovery and you can pretty much do anything.

Comment: It seems no custom recoveries are available for it though, it's a cheap device, can't blame the dev's. Full model name LYF Flame 7. The manufacturer is pretty rough with their practices too, the darn thing installs apps on its own (each of them with full set of permissions). Figured if I root it at least it would make it usable.